# How to vertically align images with different size using Semantic UI

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

Hello Stack Overflowers,
I can't figure out how to vertically align images with different size and keep them in one line?
All of these should be in one line, and column 3 should have the same height like column 1 or 2.

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dygq4.png)

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGYEAm)

```css
body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ui stackable three column grid">

  <div class="column">
    <div class="ui center aligned segment">
      <div class="ui small image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="" />
      </div><!-- image -->
      <h2 class="ui center aligned header"><i class="code icon"></i></h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vulputate lacus vitae malesuada porttitor. Vivamus commodo eleifend faucibus. Vestibulum a quam aliquam, euismod tellus eget, malesuada tellus.
        </p>
    </div><!-- segment -->
  </div><!-- column 1 -->

  <div class="column">
    <div class="ui center aligned segment">
      <div class="ui small image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="" />
      </div><!-- image -->
      <h2 class="ui center aligned header"><i class="cloud icon"></i></h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vulputate lacus vitae malesuada porttitor. Vivamus commodo eleifend faucibus. Vestibulum a quam aliquam, euismod tellus eget, malesuada tellus.
        </p>
    </div><!-- segment -->
  </div><!-- column 2 -->
  
  <div class="column">
    <div class="ui center aligned segment">
      <div class="ui small image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" />
      </div><!-- image -->
      <h2 class="ui center aligned header"><i class="hashtag icon"></i></h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vulputate lacus vitae malesuada porttitor. Vivamus commodo eleifend faucibus. Vestibulum a quam aliquam, euismod tellus eget, malesuada tellus.
        </p>
    </div><!-- segment -->
  </div><!-- column 3 -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/batrasoe/e8yb99ha/

We are setting the parent div of the image to the tallest image in the set. This will make the height of the columns to be equal.

```
.ui.small.image {

  height: 200px; /*Max Possible Height of the image */
}
```

Next, to center the images, we use the following CSS:

```
  .ui.small.image > img {

        position: absolute;  
        max-height: 100%;  
        max-width: 100%; 
        width: auto;
        height: auto;    
        top: 0;  /*Centering the image*/
        bottom: 0;    /*Centering the image*/
        left: 0;   /*Centering the image*/
        right: 0;   /*Centering the image*/
        margin: auto;
    }
```